# How to use Digitalocean's app platform component environmental variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-ocean

I am using Digital Ocean's app platform to host a NodeJS app. I do not understand the documentation for using environmental variables within my NodeJS code. https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#define-build-time-environment-variables when I try to add the environmental variable like I think the documentation wants me to I get a syntax error: `mongoose.connect(${_self.DATABASE_URL}, {useNewUrlParser: true});`
What is the correct usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:**

In your App settings you should find the App-Level Environment Variables.

You could set a variable there like this:

```
Keys: APP_LEVEL_EXAMPLE_VAR 
Values: rafiki
```

Don´t forget to save.

Now you have an App-Level Environment Variable.

**Step 2:**

In your app´s project.yml file, you can set a
variable that reads the App-Level variable like this:

```
environment: { 
  EXAMPLE_VAR: ${APP_LEVEL_EXAMPLE_VAR}
}
```

**Step 3:**

Now you can access the value of APP_LEVEL_EXAMPLE_VAR in your app like this:

```
const value = process.env.EXAMPLE_VAR
```

Comment: that does the trick! I created the App-Level Environment Variables from the browser-admin-gui in apps/settings. After that once the app automatically had built an deployd itself, the variables were available as suggested through process.env.SOME_VAR - didn't even need to edit anything in any project.yml file. Suppose the admin panel clicking did that automatically...